# scroll through output using `less` or `tail -f` while keeping the header visible

Tags: bash, tail, less

I am trying to scroll through some data formatted thus-

```
       NFI T[PSEC]   T[K]  EKIN(PSI)    E(RHO)       ECONS    ANNEE  ANNER
!>     1   0.00012     0   0.45873     16.26904     16.72777 0.30000 0.00000
!>     2   0.00024     0   1.53365     13.91887     15.45251 0.29100 0.00000
!>     3   0.00036     0   2.57649     10.44460     13.02109 0.28227 0.00000
!>     4   0.00048     0   3.27986      6.47437      9.75423 0.27380 0.00000
!>     5   0.00060     0   3.76512      2.20938      5.97450 0.26559 0.00000
!>     6   0.00073     0   4.07033     -2.21948      1.85085 0.25762 0.00000
!>     7   0.00085     0   4.01375     -6.33776     -2.32402 0.24989 0.00000
!>     8   0.00097     0   3.47760     -9.51439     -6.03679 0.24239 0.00000
!>     9   0.00109     0   2.67940    -11.61643     -8.93703 0.23512 0.00000
!>    10   0.00121     0   1.94941    -12.98344    -11.03403 0.22807 0.00000
!>    11   0.00133     0   1.42468    -13.94772    -12.52304 0.22123 0.00000
!>    12   0.00145     0   1.06924    -14.66679    -13.59755 0.21459 0.00000
!>    13   0.00157     0   0.81497    -15.20175    -14.38679 0.20815 0.00000
!>    14   0.00169     0   0.62270    -15.59298    -14.97028 0.20191 0.00000
!>    15   0.00181     0   0.47689    -15.87925    -15.40236 0.19585 0.00000
```

You can get [a larger datafile for testing your solutions here](https://gist.github.com/d3banjan/5efd650126b7c18e95fe#file-scrollable_data-dat).
Is it possible to use `tail -f` or `less` so that the header stays visible while the data keeps scrolling?